# How to disable automatic font resize in mobile browsers?

Tags: android, iphone, css, mobile

I've read what seems to be 25 different articles on disabling the automatic font resizing in phones, but nothing seems to be working.

I simply want to disable the default big text that phones display. I set the font-size to 15px, but it keeps displaying a much larger size. I've tried the following:

- -webkit-text-size-adjust:50%; (doesn't work)
- Also, when I make the font-size 10px it stays 10px, but anything bigger than that automatically becomes big text. (odd...)

How can I disable the default big text that phones display and retain the natural font-size (I want it to be 15px)?

Comment: Did you implement a css reset before displaying your stylesheet? Eric Meyer's style for example.

Comment: Actual "15 px" is reeeeally tiny in high resolution phones. Can you post code/screenshots of what is "big text"?

Comment: @dmon Actually most browsers multiply the px value by a factor based on the device resolution. E.G. `15px` becomes 45 device pixels on a 288 DPI screen.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant.